# ListFragment onListItemClick not called

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-listfragment

I'm using a `ListFragment` (Not from support library). I have a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and I'm using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`. Data shows up perfectly fine however I'm not receiving anything in the `onListItemClick` method.

I've tried to implement my own custom adapter which extends `CursorAdapter`. Again, data shows up fine however no click event is fired.

Next I tried to copy the source for the default `ListFragment` layout from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/list_content.xml). Again, no dice.

Again, i'm using [`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_2.xml/). I also attempted `simple_list_item_1`. Both are giving me an issue, i've never had problems with them before.

I'm targeting API 15+ so **I'm not using the support library**.

What else should I try to get this working?

**Edit** Code for `ListFragment` implementation. Most of which was auto-generated by Android Studio. The auto-generated code contained the support library, which I changed to a standard package.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.blah.adapters.SuggestionCursorAdapter;
import com.blah.models.DateActivity;
import com.blah.provider.Contracts;
import com.blah.provider.UpdateService;

public class DateActivityListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final String TAG = DateActivityListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    /**
     * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
     * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
     */
    private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

    /**
     * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
     * clicks.
     */
    private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

    /**
     * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
     */
    private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

    private SuggestionCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    /**
     * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
     * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
     * selections.
     */
    public interface Callbacks {
        /**
         * Callback for when an item has been selected.
         */
        public void onItemSelected(DateActivity dateActivity);

        /**
         * Callback for when a new item should be created.
         */
        public void onNewItem();
    }

    /**
     * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
     * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
     */
    private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(DateActivity dateActivity) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onNewItem() {
        }
    };

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public DateActivityListFragment() {
    }

    final static String[] FROM = {Contracts.DateActivities.C_NAME, Contracts.DateActivities.C_DESCRIPTION};
    final static int[] TO = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new SuggestionCursorAdapter(getActivity(), null);
//        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null, FROM, TO, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dateactivity_list, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
        if (savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
            setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
        }

        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    }

    /////////////// OPTIONS MENU
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.suggestion, menu);
        final ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        // Only show add button for dev user
        if (parseUser != null && !parseUser.getUsername().equals("dev")) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.menu_add).setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.menu_add) {
            mCallbacks.onNewItem();
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.menu_refresh) {
            UpdateService.startActionUpdate(getActivity());
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    /////////////// END OPTIONS MENU

    /////////////// CONTEXT MENU
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        final MenuInflater menuInflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.suggestion_context, menu);
        // Set menu title
        final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        final Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
        menu.setHeaderTitle(cursor.getString(Contracts.DateActivities.I_NAME));
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.menu_delete) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            final Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(info.position);
            // TODO promopt, are you sure first
            // delete from service.
            UpdateService.startActionDeleteItem(getActivity(), new DateActivity(cursor),
                    cursor.getLong(Contracts.DateActivities.I_ID));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    /////////////// END CONTEXT MENU

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
        mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onListItemClick");
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
        Cursor c = ((CursorAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).getCursor();
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(new DateActivity(c));
        c.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
            outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
     * given the 'activated' state when touched.
     */
    public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
        // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
        // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
        getListView().setChoiceMode(activateOnItemClick
                ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    }

    private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
        if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
        } else {
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }

        mActivatedPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        final Uri baseUri = Contracts.DateActivities.CONTENT_URI;
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
                Contracts.DateActivities.SELECT_ALL_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code for your list fragment?

Comment: Code added, see edit.

Comment: one more thing the xml for the list item.  chances are you have a field that is stealing the focus from the main list item.

Comment: I'm using simple_list_item_2, I also attempted simple_list_item_1. I've never had an issue with these layouts before.

Comment: I put a link to the layout in the desc.

Comment: what is the type of the Activity that contains this fragment? Activity or ListActivity?

Comment: If you post an answer telling me to change the parent activity from a ListActivity to an Activity then I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the parent activity to a regular Activity, not a ListActivity.

Answer (score -1):

Above answer - change parent activity from `ListActivity` to `Activity` - it worked for me